# Downloading a file using php

Tags: php, html

I uploaded a PDF file to a folder called 'forms' on my webserver.

I'm displaying data from my database onto a table, and the forms column I want to link to the file associated within the forms directory.

I've currently got the following;

```
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

$loanid         = $myrow["loanid"];
$username       = $myrow["username"];
$form           = $myrow["form"];

$table = '<tr>';

$table.= '<td>'.$loanid.'</div>';
$table.= '<td>'.$username.'</div>';
$table.= '<td><a href=\"forms/$form\">'.$form.'</a></div>';

echo $table
endwhile;
```

The table is displaying correctly and the correct file name is displaying in the forms column. However when I click the link it doesn't open the PDF as expected.

When I click the link I would imagine the link should be;
www.example.com/website/forms/form.pdf

but im receiving an object not found page and the following link;
www.example.com/"forms/$loanform/"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes does not evaluate variables and you don't need to escape double quotes in them.

Use either

```
$table.= "<td><a href=\"forms/$form\">".$form."</a></div>";
```

or

```
$table.= '<td><a href="forms/' . $form . '">' . $form . '</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, In your  your closing with  it should be  and you need to use " instead of ' when you are using php varibales in between

```
<?php
 $table = "<table>";
 while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

 $loanid         = $myrow["loanid"];
 $username       = $myrow["username"];
 $form           = $myrow["form"];

$tr = '<tr>';

$tr.= '<td>'.$loanid.'</td>';
$tr.= '<td>'.$username.'</td>';
$tr.= "<td><a href=\"forms/$form\">".$form."</a></td>";
$tr .= "</tr>";
$table .= $tr;
endwhile;
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table
?>
```